# Splitting a string object into columns

Tags: python, string, data-structures, split, data-cleaning

I am a newbie to python! And currently working on a csv file which contains column in which there is a horrible string object which looks something like this:

[image]

[image]

My questions are:

1. How do I split the data in a structured way into columns (where I choose a column name)
2. Based on the image, my concern is regarding the value **shipper** which contains values in {},how can I put that whole thing under the shipper column? Like this:

```py
shipper={"ADR":"null", "TF":[], "hints":[], "Navad":"null", "language":"null",
    "type":"null", "names":["ANDY INDUSTRIES"], "phone":"null", "id":"null", "unprocad":"null",
    "orad":"null", "email":"null"}
```

3. Based on Q2 How could I separate it as sub types? (Have one main column as Shipper and under that ADR:NULL, TF:NONE etc)
4. On other note, how can I create my own dataframe or schema based on the string value in this one cell to create my own dataframe.

I am trying the split function in python but I am not able to do exactly what I want.

I tried using:

```
df[["Date", "RA"]] = df["message"].str.split(" ", n=1, expand= True)
```

that split date and RA column but the moment I add shipper to separate I get an error "ValueError: Columns must be same length as key"

Could someone please help!!

It would be great if you could use the below in your answer so its easier forme to understand.

```
df = pd.read_csv('TF1.csv')
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be better with a bit more information on the data you have.

The `ValueError: Columns must be same length as key` error you are getting is because the column you want to split sometimes return just 1 value instead of 2. Double check that the values in that column have the character you are using in the splitting. If one of them doesn't have it, your splitting will fail.

To create a new dataframe from your data you can use `pandas.DataFrame()` and pass a suitable data structure. For instance, you can use numpy arrays, list of lists/tuples/dictionaries, dictionaries.

### From list of dictionaries

```
import pandas as pd
data = [{"name": "John", "age": 25, "occupation": "teacher"},
{"name": "Sarah", "age": 32, "occupation": "engineer"},
{"name": "Michael", "age": 47, "occupation": "consultant"},
{"name": "Emily", "age": 19, "occupation": "student"},
{"name": "Daniel", "age": 38, "occupation": "entrepreneur"},
{"name": "Rachel", "age": 29, "occupation": "doctor"},
{"name": "David", "age": 42, "occupation": "lawyer"},
{"name": "Megan", "age": 27, "occupation": "accountant"},
{"name": "Jason", "age": 34, "occupation": "software engineer"},
{"name": "Olivia", "age": 22, "occupation": "graphic designer"}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.head()

> name  age occupation
0   John    25  teacher
1   Sarah   32  engineer
2   Michael 47  consultant
3   Emily   19  student
4   Daniel  38  entrepreneur
```

### From list of tuples

```
students = [("Alice", 25), ("Bob", 30), ("Charlie", 20)]

df = pd.DataFrame(students, columns=['Name','Age'])
df.head()

> Name  Age
0   Alice   25
1   Bob 30
2   Charlie 20
```

### From a dictionary

```
my_dict = {
    "fruits": ["apple", "banana", "orange"],
    "vegetables": ["carrot", "lettuce", "broccoli"],
    "snacks": ["chips", "cookies", "pretzels"]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict)
print(df.head())

> fruits vegetables    snacks
0   apple     carrot     chips
1  banana    lettuce   cookies
2  orange   broccoli  pretzels
```